# Who is the man who assists Rand at the end of A Crown of Swords?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, robert-jordan

Just finished reading this book for the second time. I'm a little confused as to who this guy is. Rand doesn't recognise him as one of the forsaken, but he could be in a disguise. He seems to wield the True Power, but the only one who's openly done that so far is Moridin and he doesn't seem like one to help Rand out. He could be another high-up darkfriend; keeping Rand alive could be part of their plans. His description (black coat, almost as tall as Rand) doesn't really match anyone that I can remember.

I haven't read any of the Brandon Sanderson ones yet so if the answer is revealed in them then I'm happy to just read on and find out (don't want the surprise spoilt!) If, however, I should have been able to figure out who he was then I'm stumped.

Comment: Do you mean at Shadar Logoth, or the Ashaman who healed Rand right at the end? Mentioning a specific event tends to help.

Comment: I meant at Shadar Logoth. Sorry, I thought it would be obvious seeing as the guy that heals Rand (Flinn) is mentioned by name numerous times.

Comment: If you're willing to risk the spoilers, a *very* detailed analysis of this question is here: http://wotfaq.dragonmount.com/node/42

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Thanks! I've read through the series by now, and I've just started a final re-read before AMoL comes out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [A Crown of Swords: Plot Summary](http://library.tarvalon.net/index.php?title=A_Crown_of_Swords%3a_Plot_Summary) it was probably Moridin, and that seems to be confirmed by the details given on the [Ishamael - Moridin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishamael#Moridin) Wikipedia article.  (**Warning: Spoilers in that second link if you haven't read beyond CoS.**)

Comment: it *was* Moridin, so far as I could tell. He has consistently told other Forsaken to leave Rand alive, implying that Rand was _his_ to face, _his_ to decide when it was time to die.  This is consistent with the True Power wielder's decision to save Rand (at that time) in order to meet him later in the manner of his own choosing.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I've read up to Crossroads of Twilight in the past, but started again so that I was nice and 'up to date' for the Sanderson novels. I will read on.

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't believe you missed anything.  There are some more explanations in later books that will shed light on it, although I won't give any spoilers.